# How do we grep for a value and store it in a variable in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and writing a piece of script that will check for the size of the disk and calculate the free space. The code is as follows

```
$disk_space = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_LogicalDisk | Select-Object Size
$FreeSpace  = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_LogicalDisk | Select-Object FreeSpace
$space_available = $disk_space - $FreeSpace
```

I am looking to have the variables calculated and print the space_available variable. The error I receive is as follows

```
InvalidOperation: Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not 
contain a method named 'op_Subtraction'.
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't subtract a property with another property, you have to subtract the **value** of each property :) this is one way you can do what you want:

```
$disk_space = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_LogicalDisk
$space_available = $disk_space.Size - $disk_space.FreeSpace
```

You can also then do:

```
[math]::Round($space_available / 1Gb,2)
```

To get the value in Gigabytes. Note 2 is the number of decimal points.